# What is the sum of binary tree with given root and target nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have a binary tree
as a function input I have tree root and 2 nodes
I need to calculate the sum along the path between the two given nodes.

A tree example:

```
     4
   /   \
  8    13
 / \
24 45
```

Code:

```
List<Node> findPath(root, target):
if (root !=null)
    return
if root == node{
    return nodes.add(target)
}
path = findPath(root.left, target)
if (path !=null){
    return nodes.add(root).addAll(path)
}
path = findPath(root.right, target)
if (path!=null)
      return nodes.add(root).addAll(path)
```

I don't know what is the next step if I have paths to target nodes how should I calculate optimal way?

```
Input: sumTree(4, 24, 45)
Output: 8 + 24 + 45 = 77

Input: sumTree(4, 24, 13)
Output: 13 + 4 + 8 + 24 = 49

Input: sumTree(4, 4, 13)
Output: 4 + 13 = 17

Input: sumTree(4, 45, 45)
Output: 45
```

Language is JAVA but language doesn't matter unless I understand the syntax
I just want to have optimal solution.
Is it possible to provide some pseudocode?

Comment: can you provide an example input and corresponding output?

Comment: What language do you use? It is not java, or at least your code has a bunch of compilation errors. Please, come up with [mcve] before posting the question.

Comment: I think, the next step is to put  some semantic into your tree. Define how your tree should be evaluated.(now it is a bunch of numbers in a tree but without any calculation)

Comment: Given that you've found the two nodes in the tree, you need to find the deepest common ancestor. For example, given nodes 24 and 45 as inputs, the deepest common ancestor is 8. That's not too hard since the paths from the root to the nodes are identical up to that point. E.g. the paths from the root to 24 and 45 are {4,8,24} and {4,8,45}. So the common ancestor is 8, since that's the last node before the paths diverge.

Comment: @user3386109 as addition is associative and commutative you can jump around in the tree any way you want and end up with the same result as long as you traverse every node exactly one time. The only thing you need is to decide how to traverse.

Comment: @kai Sorry, but I don't see how that's relevant to what I said. Perhaps your interpretation of the OP's question is different than mine. Your comment seems to imply that the goal is to add up every node in the tree. I don't think that's the goal.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Your example uses "sumTree()", but your code uses "findPath()". It is still confusing. Are you saying: the algorithm has to A) identify the (shortest) "path" between to arbitrary nodes in the tree B) and then you want to sum up all nodes on that path?

Answer (score 1):

Your two paths will have the same prefix (at least the root should be there).
You need to remove the common prefix and add only the last (deepest) common node (once). For the parts that are different you need to add all the values. This should be `O(N)` complexity, and in-line with the rest of the solution.

Your search algorithm is not efficient because you keep copying the values from one  list to the other (`O(N^2)` if you don't have any constraints on the tree). If you modify it to build the response in place it should become `O(N)`.

Comment: Can you explain why 
Input: sumTree(4, 4, 13)
Output: 4 + 13 = 17

Input: sumTree(4, 45, 45)
Output: 45

Here for the first case I should consider 4 while in the second case only 45 ?

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan Because in the first case, the path is from 4 to 13, so the nodes included in the path are 4 and 13. In the second case, the path is from 45 to itself, so the only node in the path is 45.

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan for 4 -> 13 case: the two paths are [4] and [4, 13] the last common element is 4 and you add the parts that are different [], and [13] to get a total of 17.

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan for the 45 -> 45 case : the two paths are [4, 8, 45] and [4, 8, 45]. The last common element is 45 and you add the parts that are different [] and [] for a total of 45 + 0 + 0 = 45.